# style the Material tab layout

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-tablayout, material-components

I'm working with material design in my android app using kotlin. I wanna know how can I style my tab layout just like the way it's in the image shown below. Thanks!

[image: Tab Layout]

```
 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileFreelancerTabLayoutCu"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registeredOnValueProfileFreelancerCu"
        />
```

**SOLVED:**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileFreelancerTabLayoutCu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="60dp"
        app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator_shape"
        android:background="@drawable/thicker_stroke_tab_layout"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registeredOnValueProfileFreelancerCu"
        />
```

Comment: Post your layout

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Just use the **`app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"`** attribute to stretch the indicator to match the height and width of a tab item in this layout.
Also you can set the background color using the `app:tabIndicatorColor` attribute:

```
  <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
      app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
      app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/...."
      ...>
```

[image]

**Remove** the `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabBar"`.

Comment: ok thanks this works, but how do I get that outline and cornerRaduis?

Comment: @Aldor Currently (`1.2.0-alpha06`) the `TabLayout` in Material Component doesn't support a native shaping. You can create a selector with a shape (define in xml) and apply it with the `tabBackground` attribute, or you can wrap the `TabLayout` in a parent view with rounded corners (`CardView`, `LinearLayout`...)

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question with the solution, thanks a lot!